# Paypal Parallel payments with Expresscheckout not showing descriptions

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I use the following parameters to make a parallel payment using the express checkout.

```
`USER=<USR>' .
'&PWD=<PWD>' .
'&SIGNATURE=<SIGNATURE>' .
'&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout' .
'&RETURNURL=http://example.com/success.html' .
'&CANCELURL=http://example.com/canceled.html' .
'&VERSION=93' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=250' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=225' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=25' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Product A' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME=Product A' .            
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=<SELLER1-PAYPALEMAIL>' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART345-PAYMENT0' .              
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=USD' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=75' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=65' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=10' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Sale' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=Extra Fee' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME=Extra Fee' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=<SELLER2-PAYPALEMAIL>' .
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART543-PAYMENT1';`
```

I get a token back and an ACK success but when I submit this token using

```
'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='<TOKEN>;'
```

The confirmation page is displayed but there are no product descriptions.
I get 2 items in the summary

```
'SELLER1 name 225 
Tax 25
SELLER2 name  65
Tax10        
Total         325'
```

I was expecting

```
'SELLER1 name
 Product A     225
 Tax 25
 SELLER2 name
 Extra Fee      65
 Total         325'
```

Does any body know how to get this result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display line items on the checkout page, you must pass line item variables.  They begin with "L_"

Comment: That worked thanks I just had to add the 'L_' parameters as suggested. But also note I had to add all the parameters L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0